# Enabling vcan0 interface using systemd on boot time

Tags: interface, systemd, boot, can-bus

Just trying to find the most convenient way to enable vcan0 (socketcan) interface on boot time using systemd. My current solution is described below. First of all, a script used to check if vcan0 is enabled and set it up when it is not enabled yet.

```
$ cat /usr/bin/vcan0.sh
#! /bin/sh
ifconfig vcan0 > /dev/null 2>&1
RET=$?
if [ $RET -ne 0 ]; then
    ip link add name vcan0 type vcan
    ip link set dev vcan0 up
fi
```

Then a unit service calling previous script:

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/vcan0.service 
[Unit]
Description=Bring-up vcan0
[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vcan0.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Can you suggest some better or more convenient method to get this working using systemd? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved id by using the systemd's netdev capabilities.

Create the netdev config file `/etc/systemd/network/vcan0.netdev` with the following content:

```
[NetDev]
Name=vcan0
Kind=vcan

[vcan]
```

After reloading the configuration with `sudo networkctl reload` you can see the following `networkctl list` output:

```
IDX LINK            TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo              loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 eno1            ether    routable    configured
  7 vcan0           can      carrier     unmanaged

3 links listed.
```

After that i was able to write and read from `vcan0`.